# Continuous functions using interval notation

Tags: functions

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x-2}$. Use interval notation to indicate where $f(x)$ is continuous.
I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: When are the solutions for $\sqrt{x-2}$ real? Can you take the square roots of negative numbers?

Comment: Are you saying you cannot figure where $f(x)$ is continuous, or that you do not know how to write that set in interval notation?

Comment: I do not know where f(x) is continuous

Comment: The function $f(x)$ is continuous on its entire domain.  At $x = 2$, it is continuous from the right.  If it were discontinuous, its graph would contain a hole, a jump, an asymptote, or oscillate infinitely often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$[2,\infty)$
The function has restrictions on its domain. $x-2$ has to be greater than or equal to $0$. Solving this inequality, $x \geq 2$. Therefore, continuous from $2$ to $\infty$.